# Создать перенаправление в папку уровнем выше - Apache, htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

На хостинге по умолчанию сайт размещается в public_html
Но мне нужно подняться на уровень выше и разместить его в свою папку <имя сайта> (который находится на одном уровне с public_html>

Модифицирую такой код:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/frontend/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?website.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ frontend/ [L]
```

Он делает редирект во вложенный папку /frontend/, но мне нужно подняться на уровень выше и сделать переадресацию в папку /frontend (еще раз: папка  находится на одном уровне с public_html)

Сколько не модифицировал этот код - не работает (менял "/frontend/" на "/../sitename/frontend/"). Такое ощущение, что не разрешает подниматься на уровень выше.

Comment: А apache умеет обрабатывать запросы вне корневой папки сайта и ее вложенных подпапок?

Answer (score 1):

Есть у меня подозрение что для данного VirtualHost установлен доступ только для public_html (обычно так всегда и делают).

mod_rewrite по сути работает в пределах http. Если по данному пути в пределах данного домена нельзя попасть, то редирект не сработает (а http так вообще не позволяет выходить за пределы корня сайта).

В качестве обходного варианта можно предложить сделать символическую ссылку и разрешить по ним ходить в данном сайте (`Options +FollowSymLinks`)